# Launch a bundled external script when exporting to AppImage

Tags: javascript, electron, electron-builder, appimage

I have made my own application with electron, and I encounter an issue with production builds, when it comes to launching an external python script.

When I run the code in the dev environment, I have something like:

`const out = spawnSync(PYTHON_LOCATION, ['-d', '-j', '-p', path, tempfile]);`

and it works well because `PYTHON_LOCATION` is `public/python.py`.

However, when I use electron-builder to make an AppImage, this does not work because the script can't obviously be found. An AppImage application is a single file and it's obvious that the public directory is not exported with it.

Is there a solution to this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When an AppImage is executed the `AppDir` variable is set on the process environment so you have to check whether that variable exists and is set. Then you can build the right path to your python script.

Answer (score 0):

Electron bundles most things into an `app.asar` file that probably holds the file that you want. The problem is, there are one or two well intentioned suggestions on the web that AppImage files need to be queried *relative* to the container itself, which is unfortunately a bit misleading. The reality is, no amount of these variations will work as I'm sure you discovered:

```
./PYTHON_LOCATION
/PYTHON_LOCATION
PYTHON_LOCATION
```

The solution is that you need to use `__dirname` to find out where the image is. Its most likely somewhere like this folder when you run the AppImage (but of course, **not** when you run from the IDE):

`/tmp/.mount_YourApplicationNameHVTcDI/`

And so `__dirname` is (assuming the app was built from an `app/electron/` folder:

`/tmp/.mount_YourApplicationNameHVTcDI/resources/app.asar/app/electron`

So your solution will be something like:

`Path.join(__dirname, PYTHON_LOCATION)`

Even though Electron is a looking at resources in an `app.asar` file, it is transparent to the file system and just looks like a folder. Hence you can see inside it using normal file I/O commands.

Remember that in the IDE, `__dirname` will be totally different, so the file will need to be there as well.